# uniform variable causing problems in fragment shader

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, glsl, glsles

This is my fragment shader code. Its an implementation of Gradient Map function.

```
varying vec2 v_TextureCoord;
uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;

uniform sampler2D u_GradientTexture;
uniform float u_FilParOne;

const highp vec3 W = vec3(0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140);

void main() {
   lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(sTexture, v_TextureCoord);
   float gray = dot(textureColor.rgb, W);
   float samplePoint = (0.2 + ((1.0 - 0.2) * gray));
   vec4 map = texture2D(u_GradientTexture, vec2(samplePoint, 5.0));
   gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(map), textureColor.a);
}
```

Note the line

```
float samplePoint = (0.2 + ((1.0 - 0.2) * gray));
```

the 0.2 there is something I would like to replace with a parameter. so I used the uniform u_FilParOne. But when I replace the 0.2 with that variable like this:

```
float samplePoint = (u_FilParOne + ((1.0 - u_FilParOne) * gray));
```

my program runs but the Screen just keeps cycling through random colors.

when I replace all the code in the main function with

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(u_FilParOne, u_FilParOne, u_FilParOne, 1.0);
```

My screen turns gray and when i change the value of the uniform from my java code with the lines :

```
filterParameterOne=0.2f;      
glUniform1f(mUniformFilterParameterOneHandle, filterParameterOne);
```

I can control the lightness and darkness of the gray, Which means that the value is being sent correctly from Java to OpenGL.

Is there something I am missing here? Why can't I use the uniform in the original program itself?

Comment: Sounds like a driver bug to me.

Comment: It wouldn't explain the problem, but what's the reason for using 5.0 as the second texture coordinate?

Comment: @RetoKoradi : no particular reason as such . my texture happens to be 30 px in height and that so I guess i could sample from anywhere between 0 to 30.

Comment: Texture coordinates are in the range 0.0 to 1.0, so 5.0 would either wrap around a few times, or be clamped, depending on your texture sampling attributes.

Comment: @RetoKoradi : aaah. right. my texture was wraping around thats why I think i could get away by setting the coordinate to a value greater than 1.0. But thank you for this. I'll keep it in mind and now have set it to 0.5.

Comment: To me this sounds like you're mixing up your uniform locations

Comment: @LJᛃ but I am able to use the variable without the formula.

like i said if i commment out the  formula, I can still use the variable like
gl_FragColor = vec4(u_FilParOne, u_FilParOne, u_FilParOne, 1.0);

and i am able to change the value of u_FilParOne from my Java code and see the color change

Comment: commenting out that formula results in your sampler uniforms becoming unused and optimized away leaving only your `u_FilParOne` uniform at location `0` while otherwise it could be at any location between `0` and `3`.